# JAX WS webservice receives null parameters when part accessor elements are qualified with namespaces

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have implemented a web service using Netbeans 7.0 and JAX-WS.

When the web service is called by Soap UI it works as it should. When it is called by SAP CRM the web service implementation receives null parameters: in the example below the userId is null instead of "foo". (userId is of type String)

The SOAP message sent by SOAP UI is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:IciSystemInterface">
       <soapenv:Header>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <urn:getWorkcenterCapability>
             <userId>foo</userId>
          </urn:getWorkcenterCapability>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The SOAP message sent by SAP CRM is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <pre:user xmlns:pre="urn:IciSystemInterface" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0" xsi:type="xsd:string">IC_AGENT_SRV</pre:user> 
      <pre:language xmlns:pre="urn:IciSystemInterface" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0" xsi:type="xsd:string">EN</pre:language> 
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <ns0:getWorkcenterCapability xmlns:ns0="urn:IciSystemInterface">
       <userId xmlns="urn:IciSystemInterface">foo</userId> 
     </ns0:getWorkcenterCapability>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I remove the xmlns property from the userId tag it works (I made the change and tested it by calling the web service using an HTTP client):

```
    <ns0:getWorkcenterCapability xmlns:ns0="urn:IciSystemInterface">
       <userId>foo</userId> 
    </ns0:getWorkcenterCapability>
```

The problem is I can't change the way SAP CRM makes its calls. Is there a way I can make JAX WS ignore part accessor elements' namespaces?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possbile to solve this with a web service handler?

Comment: It probably is, but then I would have to process every message of every method of my service. Is there a way to force JAX-WS to comply to SOAP 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Branden's advice. I used SoapHandler to trap calls to the web service and process the soap message before JAX-WS calls my web service implementation. It worked.